# Keras Erro: Graph disconnected

Tags: keras, graph, model

The following code snippet is giving error (Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor):

`x = Concatenate (axis = 1) (submodel_outputs)` 
 `parallel_layers = Model (inputs = embedding_layers [0] .input, outputs = x)`

The value of embedding_layers [0] .get_input_at (0) is equal to: 
`<tf.Tensor 'embedding_8_input: 0' shape = (?, 100) dtype = float32>`

The variable x is the concatenation of 3 models, such as:

- embedding_8 (Embedding) -    (None, 100, 300)

  dropout_22 (Dropout) -  (None, 100, 300)

  skip_conv1d_22 (SkipConv1D- (None, 100, 100)

  max_pooling1d_22 (MaxPooling)(None, 25, 100)

I've tried everything, but the error continues. What do I do to make the following line work:
`parallel_layers = Model (inputs = embedding_layers [0] .input, outputs = x)`

Answer (score 0):

This error means that your model input and output are not connected. Please paste your full model definition, and this should help others help you.